# Wicket Ajax Error Log: ERROR: Cannot bind a listener for event "click" on element "AjaxCheckBox" because the element is not in the DOM

Tags: javascript, ajax, dom, wicket, wicket-6

Hey when I run my program, I want to dynamically add Panels to the mainpage and therfore work with "setVisible(boolean)".
But not I get the error:
*ERROR: Cannot bind a listener for event "click" on element "institutCheck7" because the element is not in the DOM*
In the Ajax Debugger.

I saw that it has something to do with the visibility in this
[post](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/WICKET-5690), but I didn't get what I have to do, it says, that this is being resolved in Wicket 7, but I'm still running 6.20.

```
adminUIForm.add(myPanel= new MyPanel("myPanel", allThings));
    myPanel.setOutputMarkupId(true);
    myPanel.setVisible(false);
    //Note: Setting the OutputMarkupId allows actions such as setting components in/visible
    
    List<IColumn<ContactInfo, String>> columns = new ArrayList<IColumn<ContactInfo, String>>();
    columns = initializeColumns(columns);

    DataTable<ContactInfo, String> datatable = new DataTable<ContactInfo, String>("datatable", columns, provider, 10){
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        @Override
        protected Item<ContactInfo> newRowItem(final String id, final int index,
                final IModel<ContactInfo> model) {
            Item<ContactInfo> rowItem = new Item<ContactInfo>(id, index, model);
            rowItem.add(new AjaxEventBehavior("onclick") {

                private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

                @Override
                protected void onEvent(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
                    System.out.println("click");
                    myPanel.setSelectedKontakt(model);
                    myPanel.setVisible(true);
                    target.add(myPanel);
                }
            });
            return rowItem;
        }
    };
    setTableProperties(datatable);
    adminUIForm.add(datatable);
}
```

I override the newRowItem method to add an onClick event. I get "click" in the console each time I hit a column, but I get this error log:

> ERROR: Wicket.Ajax.Call.processComponent: Component with id [[institutTablePanel6]] was not found while trying to perform markup update. Make sure you called component.setOutputMarkupId(true) on the component whose markup you are trying to update.
>
> ERROR: Cannot bind a listener for event "click" on element "institutCheck7" because the element is not in the DOM
>
> ERROR: Cannot bind a listener for event "click" on element "cont8" because the element is not in the DOM
>
> ERROR: Cannot bind a listener for event "click" on element "institutCheck9" because the element is not in the DOM
>
> ERROR: Cannot bind a listener for event "click" on element "conta" because the element is not in the DOM
>
> ERROR: Cannot bind a listener for event "click" on element "institutCheckb" because the element is not in the DOM
>
> ERROR: Cannot bind a listener for event "click" on element "contc" because the element is not in the DOM
>
> ERROR: Cannot bind a listener for event "click" on element "institutCheckd" because the element is not in the DOM
>
> ERROR: Cannot bind a listener for event "click" on element "conte" because the element is not in the DOM

Those error all bind with components in "myPanel", I don't know how to resolve this. If I set it to visible earlier I get the same problem, including all elements, which will be hidden later in the workflow.

Edit:

```
public class MyPanel extends Panel {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private Form<Void> institutForm = new Form<Void>("institutForm");
private ListView<Institut> listView;
private IModel<ContactInfo> selectedKontakt;
private Set<Institut> allInstitut;

@Override
protected void onModelChanged() {
    //TODO maybe here
    super.onModelChanged();
}

public InstitutTablePanel(String id, final Set<Institut> allInstitut) {
    super(id);
    this.allInstitut = allInstitut;

    this.add(institutForm);

    List<Institut> allInstitutList = new ArrayList<Institut>(allInstitut);

    institutForm.add(listView = new ListView<Institut>("listView", allInstitutList) {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        protected void populateItem(final ListItem<Institut> item) {
            final IModel<Boolean> checked = Model.of(Boolean.FALSE);
            final IModel<String> expandState = Model.of("+");
            @SuppressWarnings("unused")
            final Label institutLabel;
            final Institut institut = item.getModelObject();
            // Define variables which concern only one item in populateItem
            
            final WebMarkupContainer div = createMarkUpContainer("cont");
            final WebMarkupContainer container = createMarkUpContainer("container");

            container.setEnabled(false);
            
            compareInstitute(checked, institut, container);
            item.add(container);
            
            div.add(new AjaxEventBehavior("onclick") {
                private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

                @Override
                protected void onEvent(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
                    expandOrCollapse(expandState, container);
                    target.add(institutForm);
                }
            });

            item.add(div);
            div.add(new AjaxCheckBox("institutCheck", checked) {
                private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

                @Override
                protected void onUpdate(AjaxRequestTarget target) {

                    //Not Important for this
                    target.add(institutForm);
                }
            });
            container.add(new ErhebungMatrixPanel("erhebungMatrix", institut, selectedKontakt));
            container.setVisible(false);
            div.add(institutLabel = new Label("institutLabel", new PropertyModel<Institut>(institut, "langName")));
        }
    });
    listView.setOutputMarkupId(true);
    listView.setReuseItems(true);
    institutForm.setOutputMarkupId(true);

}}
```

I edited my setSelectedKontakt method like this:

```
public void setSelectedKontakt(IModel<ContactInfo> model) {
    this.selectedKontakt = model;
    modelChanged();
}
```

to trigger the change if necessary.
The problem is `target.add(myPanel);` won't trigger populateItem again.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The error message says it pretty clearly and a look into the DOM tells that the markup for the panel is not there. Thats because `setVisible(false)` doens't even render the component with CSS `display: none;` as expected. It's just not there so it can't be modified afterwards. But you can tell Wicket to render a placeholder instead with `setOutputMarkupPlaceholderTag(true)`. Wicket then creates an invisible markup e.g. `<span style="display: none;" id="mypanel1a"></span>`, which then is swaped with the real component when setting the visiblity to `true` later.

Comment: This solved the problem to a certain point, now when I select a row item for the first time, I get a new Panel, but it does not change afterwards, eventhough the model changes (tested in debugger).

Comment: How did you connect the model of `MyPanel` to the Labels (i guess you're using Labels to display the contact informations)? I assume you're hard wiring the fields from the contact to the labels hence the output won't change on AJAX event.

Comment: I know saw, that `target.add(myPanel);` does not trigger the populateItem method again in myPanel, eventhough I guess it should because `target.add();` has to re-render the whole Panel (?)

Comment: It is hard to get the bug when you don't share the code of `MyPanel`.

Comment: Made an edit on my original post. It does not really fit in the same problem domain, as the original question, so I hasitated to add the code.

Answer (score 1):

Just a tip to those that do get this error that a common mistake is to use:

```
<wicket:container wicket:id="panel"/>
```

...instead of...

```
<div wicket:id="panel"/>
```

...for where you put the panel. The method call `setOutputMarkupId` will not inform you that it is unable to add an id to a `wicket:container`, and hence your `target.add(panel)` will also fail.